# Django Nginx Gunicorn DEBUG Flag Error

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I rechecked all my configuration settings as suggested in the [tutorial](http://markwingerd.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/setting-up-django-with-ubuntu-12-10-sqlite-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-a-digital-ocean-droplet/) to setup my app on digitalocean.

I changed the DEBUG flag in settings.py to True and set the ALLOWED_HOST variable - in this case I get the "It worked" page of Django at www.example.co - nginx and gunicorn all seem to work. When I change the DEBUG flag to False. I get "400" or "URL not found" error at www.example.co

Can some one tell, where is this going wrong? one change in flag and there is error

Solved - simple solution was to have landing page at root '/', gunicorn and nginx work well.. with config suggested in the tutorial

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Update your bind argument for gunicorn_django to 127.0.0.1:8000

```
/opt/venv/bin/gunicorn_django --bind 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Comment: Thanks! changed the bind argument. But the problem seems to come place else. In the django settings.py, when I change the DEBUG flag to True, my www.example.co site shows the django "it works" page. The moment i set it to False, I get the errors.

Comment: Trys setting ALLOWED_HOSTS to ['*',]